# how to prove $f(x) = x^a$ is continous?

Tags: real-analysis

When the range of $x$ is greater than zero and $a$ is irrational number
I don't know how to prove $f(x)=x^a$ is continous
I have already tried convolution

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Write it as $x^a = e^{a \ln(x)}$, use theorems of calculus to derive continuity of $\ln(x)$ and of $e^x$, and then use that the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: The most important thing to ask before doing the proof is what is the *definition* of $x^a$ as @mixedmath points out in his answer.

Comment: "I have already tried convolution"? Seriously? How did you try it and why you would expect that could be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may depend on how you define $x^a$.

You might define it as a limit of functions $x^{a_n}$ where $a_n$ are rationals approaching $a$, in which case you might try to show that on any finite closed interval, you have a sequence of uniformly continuous functions converging uniformly. This would suffice.

Or you might define $x^a$ as $e^{a \ln x}$, in which case you would want to prove the continuity of $e^x$ and $\ln x$, and that compositions of continuous functions are continuous. Of course one needs to define $e^x$ and $\ln x$ in order to prove that they're continuous, and these can also be done in a variety of ways. One way might be to define $e^x$ as its power series, and consider the functions
$$f_n(x) = \sum_{m \leq n} \frac{x^m}{m!},$$
which on any finite closed interval are uniformly continuous functions which converge uniformly to $e^x$. Thus $e^x$ is continuous. Furthermore, $e^x$ is increasing and therefore invertible, so its inverse $\ln x$ is also continuous.

The point is that when you're proving something, especially a fundamental fact, the form of the proof will depend heavily on the context.

Comment: Hello. Time has passed, but I have a question from your answer. The question is how to prove first paragraph method(define it as a limit of functions) Can you tell me specifically? it doesn't work well. and what if Given question's variable a is not irrational but rational?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following for $a>1$:

let's see how delta-epsilon proof will work:
$$|x-n|<\delta,\ |x^a-n^a|=|x-n|\left|\frac{x^a-n^a}{x-n}\right|<\epsilon$$now we can bound $|x-n|<1$ so:$$-1<x-n<1\implies x<1+n\\\implies\frac{x^a-n^a}{x-n}<\frac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{(n+1)-n}=(n+1)^a-n^a\\\implies|x-n|\left|\frac{x^a-n^a}{x-n}\right|<|x-n||(n+1)^a-n^a|\\<|x-n|\left((n+1)^a-n^a\right)<\delta\left((n+1)^a-n^a\right)=\epsilon\\\therefore\delta:=\min\left(1,\frac{\epsilon}{(n+1)^a-n^a}\right)$$
now lets check:$$|x^a-n^a|=|x-n|\left|\frac{x^a-n^a}{x-n}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{(n+1)^a-n^a}\times\left((n+1)^a-n^a\right)=\epsilon$$
so we have $$\lim_{x\to n}x^a=n^a,\forall a>1,\text{ and that the function is continues}$$
You can also see that for $-1<a<0$ all of what I did is also true, this is true because my proof is based on the fact that $n^a<(n+1)^a$. Now as you may see this is false when $0<a<1$, but when a is negative $<$ become $>$ and vice versa, so when $0>a>-1$, $x^a$ is equal to $n^a$ and continues.

I can't see why this won't apply on irrational numbers but if it is not please correct me